# Is there a Lock implementation that performs deadlock detection?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

The [Java Docs for Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lockInterruptibly%28%29) contain the following statement in documentation of the Methods `lock`, `lockInterruptibly` and `tryLock`.

> A Lock implementation may be able to detect erroneous use of the lock, such as an invocation that would cause deadlock, and may throw an (unchecked) exception in such circumstances. The circumstances and the exception type must be documented by that Lock implementation.

Is there any implementation of the `Lock` Interface in the Java 8 API that actually attempts to detect such "erroneous use"?

Comment: Note how the javadoc says that a deadlock is _one_ possible misuse. Another possible misuse is try and unlock a lock which has already been unlocked; and all available implementations do that (I believe they throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException` in that case; haven't checked)

Comment: I'm specifically asking about locking - I couldn't find any implementation mentioning throwing anything other than InterruptedException on `tryLock`... I know that unlocking a Lock you don't own quote "may throw an (unchecked) exception", but that is something different.

Comment: If third party libraries are fair game, Guava's [`CycleDetectingLockFactory`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/CycleDetectingLockFactory.html) might be the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks, certainly interesting. Looking into it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some more research I came to the conclusion that the answer is apparently:

**No.** None of the Lock implementations in the standard Java 8 API attempt to do something like that.

There are however some libraries that have mechanisms for detecting (potential) deadlocks that make use of the explicit permission to throw `RuntimeException`s that is given in the Java Doc of the lock methods. One example for such a mechanism is [Guava's CycleDetectingLockFactory](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/CycleDetectingLockFactory.html) that was mentioned by Louis Wasserman in the comments.